# Filter on modal popup not appearing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have built the following website: [Website link](http://staging.allaboutyou.com.au/search/members)

When no results are returned (you can do this by choosing Australian capital in state drop-down) to the page the filter which is a bootstrap modal popup struggles to be displayed by that I mean you only see a fraction of it as shown here:

http://res.cloudinary.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/v1442111067/searchpage_gjuljm.png

HTML

```
<div class="filter-toggle" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#filterModal"><i class="fa fa-filter"></i></div>

<div class="modal" id="filterModal" tabindex="1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!--Here goes filters dynamically pasted by jQuery-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $filterToggle = $('.filter-toggle');
    //Filter Toggle / Showing Filters in Modal
    $filterToggle.click(function () {
        $('.shop-filters').appendTo($('#filterModal .modal-body'));
        $('#filterModal .modal-body .shop-filters').css('display', 'block');
    });

    $('#filterModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
        $('.shop-filters').appendTo('.filters-mobile');
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(window).width() > 768) {
            $('#filterModal').modal('hide');
        }
    });
</script>
```

And I'm struggling to grasp what could be causing this issue, now when tested on the desktop everything works as expected but on iPad behaving strangely showing in snapshot

Comment: I can't see the problem with modal on any screen size and on chrome and firefox

Comment: @Shehary what even on Ipad?

Comment: Oouch, i have to go to Apple store to buy one to check, you should mention this in your question so it will easy to track down the issue that you are facing only on IOS devices

Comment: @Shehary surprised I actually missed that off!, but yes its ipad apologies.

Comment: I see you are using jQuery append to call the data into modal, i suggest don't do like this do it with the Ajax, there is nothing wrong with the HTML but only this jQuery looks fishy fishy to me :)

Comment: @Shehary ok thanks for letting me know

Comment: can you reproduce the issue on fiddle ?